# How to monitor queries sent to Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

For debugging purposes, we want to monitor the queries that our .Net application (hosted on Azure) is sending to Elastic Search (hosted at QBox).  We have a problem with terms that are not well mapped / included in the REST call and want to have a view on what is exactly sent to ES.

thx
Marc

Comment: Have you tried just a straight logging HTTP proxy and pointing your .net client at the logging proxy?

Comment: A bit difficult to put in a live environment a proxy between the Azure web role which is doing requests towards QBox Rest adapter.  I would have hoped that there is a plugin in ES to monitor live requests.  There are som many plugins out there but they all focus on stats and on cluster status.

Comment: The following article explains how to monitor queries using Packetbeat: https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the NEST client for Elasticsearch. You can get access to the actual JSON request being sent to your Elasticsearch index by examining the `ConnectionStatus` property of your search response.

I am doing this today in my application with something similar to the following:

```cs
   var response = client.Search<ElasticsearchProject>(s => s
           .Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
   var connectionStatus = response.ConnectionStatus;

   //output search request send to Elasticsearch
   Console.WriteLine(connectionStatus.Request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the elasticsearch-jetty plugin a try. It supports configurable request logging:

> Overview
>
> The elasticsearch-jetty plugin brings full power of Jetty and adds
>   several new features to elasticsearch. With this plugin elasticsearch
>   can now handle SSL connections, support basic authentication, and log
>   all or some incoming requests in plain text or json formats.

https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty

I've not yet used it myself but we are considering it for debugging of malformed queries.

Or you can try using the slow query log mechanism with the threshold set to 0 ms:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html

Comment: I've added another approach, using the slow query log with the threshold set to 0 ms -

Comment: I guess that's too old, I can't even get the plugin to install.